# Azure WebJobs: Queue triggers with different batch sizes

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-queues

I have a WebJob on azure that processes messages from multiple queues at the same time:

```
public async static Task ProcessQueueMessage1([QueueTrigger("queue1")] string message)
    {


        switch (message.Substring(message.Length - 3, 3))
        {
            case "tze":
                await Parser.Process1(message);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    public async static Task ProcessQueueMessage2([QueueTrigger("queue2")] string message)
    {


        switch (message.Substring(message.Length - 3, 3))
        {
            case "tzr":
                await Parser.Process2(message);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

And the in the MAIN

```
static void Main()
    {

        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.Queues.BatchSize = 3;
        config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 1;
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();

    }
```

here: `message.Substring(message.Length - 3, 3)` just checks the extension of the file.

My question is, how would I go on about making the batch size of queue1 different than queue2, can I make second jobhost with a different configuration and have `host.RunAndBlock()` and `host2.RunAndBlock()`?? How would I specify what queue should the jobhost do?

I have also tried the Groupqueuetriggers, but unfortunately they take  of string, and in my situation I cannot actually pass lists to the queue. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to tackle this you need to provide a custom implementation of IQueueProcessorFactory. You only need one JobHost.

There's an example on how to do this [here.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/CustomQueueProcessorFactory.cs)

```
    static void Main()
    {

        //Configure JobHost
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.Queues.BatchSize = 32;
        config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 6;
        // Create a custom configuration
        // If you're using DI you should get this from the kernel
        config.Queues.QueueProcessorFactory = new CustomQueueProcessorFactory();

        //Pass configuration to JobJost
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

And in the **CustomQueueProcessorFactory** you can insert the custom configuration based on the queue name.

```
public class CustomQueueProcessorFactory : IQueueProcessorFactory
{
    public QueueProcessor Create(QueueProcessorFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        if (context.Queue.Name == "queuename1")
        {
            context.MaxDequeueCount = 10;
        }
        else if (context.Queue.Name == "queuename2")
        {
            context.MaxDequeueCount = 10;
            context.BatchSize = 1;
        }

        return new QueueProcessor(context);
    }
}
```